# How can I say "to get one's hair cut"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I notice that my friend's hair is shorter than the last time I saw the person, I want to comment on this, but I don't know how to say it Esperanto. These are some options I have thought of:

- Ĉu vi tondis viajn harojn? (Verŝajne la persono ne mem tondis ilin per tondilo)
- Ĉu vi lasis tondi viajn harojn?
- Ĉu vi iris al frizisto? (Sed foje estas familiano aŭ amiko kiu helpis, kaj ne nepre profesiulo)
- Ĉu vi havas novan harstilon? (Sed foje estas la sama stilo, nur malpli longa)

Answer (score 9):

You can say:

> Ĉu vi tondigis vian hararon?

Although this might seem like you are asking whether the person caused their hair to cut something, it is actually common to use *-ig-* with a transitive verb, and in that case the object of the new verb can refer to either the subject or the object of the original verb. So in this case *tondigi hararon* is technically ambiguous and could mean either that you caused the hair to be cut or that you caused the hair to cut something. However in the context it is clear that you probably don’t mean the latter. [PMEG has a description of this](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj_frazroloj/ig.html#i-598) with examples.

There are some examples of this phrase from Tekstaro:

> Jen kion ni faros, Borenka: tri tagojn mi ne drinkos, por ke mia ruĝeblua vizaĝo reordiĝu, poste mi venos al vi kaj vi pruntos al mi kostumon; mi min razos, **tondigos miajn harojn**, poste vi veturos al ŝi kaj ŝin venigos en vian hejmon.
>
> Tiele, la sikaj viroj malĝoje ĉesas surporti turbanon kaj unuafoje en la vivo vizitas barbirojn por **fortondigi la hararon kaj barbon**.

Answer (score 2):

*Lasi tondi* strikes me as a little old fashioned, but it is not unheard of.

- Vole nevole Trebinto lasas fortondi sian belan barbon

*Tondigi* is of course also possible. Actually, all your suggestions sound reasonable and I would notice anything strange about them in context. To your list I would also add ***Ĉu vi havas novan hararanĝon?*** It's what they used in *Esperanto Pasporto al la Tuta Mondo*

https://youtu.be/JiiUM-zYMog?t=49s

Comment: In addition, I think *lasi tondi* is a little more passive in sound (not exactly "allow to be cut" but more in that direction) in contrast to the *tondigi* ("had it cut").

Comment: This could be a topic for a new question - but I would assert that the intended meaning of "lasi X-i" is generally the same as "to have something done." My only hesitation is whether this is good Esperanto, or an archaism based on German usage. I'm inclined to say the latter.

Answer (score 1):

I would offer an alternative, funny as it might seem: "Ĉu vi tondiĝis?"
Context is king, and since a person doesn't ever get "tondita", it's obvious that you speak about the hair. I found one occurence in the tekstaro.com, from the New Testament:

> Ĉar se virino ne estas vualita, ŝi ankaŭ tondiĝu; sed se estas
>   hontinde por virino esti kun haroj tonditaj aŭ razitaj, ŝi estu
>   vualita.

A similar construction is used in Romanian, where that question would be "Te-ai tuns?" Explanation: "*ai*" is an auxiliary verb (to have) used to create the past tense "*ai tuns*" of the verb "*(RO)a tunde=(EO)tondi*". "*Te*" means "*yourself*" and is used to create reflexive verbs just like "*-iĝ*".

Answer (score 0):

From the tekstaro:

- En tiu tago oni unuafoje **tondis la harojn**...
- ...Moabon, kaj ĉiujn, kiuj **tondas la harojn** sur la tempioj...
- Por kelkaj asoj ŝi **tondis la harojn** de la plej malriĉaj klientoj.
- Mi **detondigis la hararon** kaj vendis ĝin...
- Vi **detondigis la hararon**?

Comment: Almenaux la tria temas pri tondi ies harojn (mem uzante la tondilon). Mia demando tamen temis pri la inversa vidpunkto, kion diri kiam onia propra hararo estis tondita de iu alia. Kion faris la klientoj?

Comment: @AntoniaMontaro "Li tondis miajn harojn."