# How to express "to have something done"?

Tags: phrase-requests

How to express the idea of having something done for you? For instance:

> I have washed my laundry.
>
> I have my laundry washed.

Can *-igi* be used for this?

> *Mi [lesivis](http://vortaro.net/#lesivi) miajn lesivaĵojn.*
>
> *Mi lesivigis miajn lesivaĵojn.*

Addendum:

I kept wading some dictionaries and found, that *lesivi* for doing laundry seems to be somewhat old-fashioned. The normal *lavi* is better. For laundry I found better expressions: *lavotaĵo* (for laundry to be done, dirty laundry) and *lavitaĵo* (for done laundry, clean laundry). I think *vestaĵoj* is too narrow, because laundry can also be towels, bed-sheets and other non-clothes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use *-ig-* for this. If you say:

> Mi lavigis miajn vestaĵojn

Technically that could mean either that you caused your clothes to wash something or that you caused something/someone to wash your clothes. But obviously the second meaning is much more likely because the first one doesn’t make much sense.

PMEG has more examples of this kind of use of -ig- [here](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/ig.html#i-g6g).

> Oni ankaŭ povas deiri de objekta verbo. La objekto de tia IG-verbo estas aŭ la subjekto de la simpla verbo, aŭ la objekto de la simpla verbo
>
> […]
>
> • *Mi ne povis **komprenigi** la ŝercon al li.*

There is also a [very similar question](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2760/how-can-i-say-to-get-ones-hair-cut) about getting your hair cut.

Answer (score -1):

Mi ne uzus *ig* en tiu situacio. Por mi tio estas [konfuza](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj_frazroloj/ig.html#i-aa4) (vidu la ekzemplon *sciigi*) kaj povas ankaŭ [elvoki ideon de dev(ig)o aŭ trudo](http://vortaro.net/#ig).

*IG* povas esti tre trompa ĉe kelkaj tipoj de radikoj. En via ekzemplo, *lesiv/* estas substantiva radiko, do *lesivigi* **nur** signifus *igi ion lesivo/lesiva* **ne** *igi iun lesivi*.

La difino de [*ig*](http://vortaro.net/#ig) montras kiel malsame *ig* agas, laŭ la tipo de radiko, kaj donas klarigon kaj ekzemplojn. Uzi ĝin, ĉefe sufikse, ne ĉiam estas simpla afero.

Simpla formo:

```
Oni lavis miajn vestaĵojn.
```

Se vi vere volas substreki la fakton, ke vi estus povinta tion mem fari, sed preferis transdoni la taskon al iu alia, vi povus aldoni verbon, kiu klarigos la tipon de transdono:

```
Mi pagis, por ke oni lavu de miajn vestaĵojn.
Mi petis, ke oni lavu miajn vestaĵojn.
Mi lasis ilin lavi miajn vestaĵojn.
```

Jen frazo el Kastelo de Prelongo:

```
li ĝentile elirigis la kapitanon kaj petis ke oni senvestigu Josefinon
```

Comment: Mi trovas vian unuan sugeston iom stranga, kvazaŭ iu neatendite lavis la vestaĵojn kaj oni estas surprizita.

Comment: @NeilRoberts, ĉu en la frazo _oni proponis mian ideon_ vi sentas tiun saman surprizon kaj neatenditecon?

Comment: Estas klasika ekzemplo “Mi tondigis mian hararon” por diri, ke mi iris al frizisto, kiu tondis miajn harojn. Ankaŭ via ekzemplo “Mi lasis ilin lavi miajn vestaĵojn.” ne havas la celatan signifon; tio signifas, ke vi ne kontraŭstaris/permesis iun lavi viajn vestaĵojn, sed ne implicas iun ajn peton. Komparu “Mi igis ŝin foriri” kaj “Mi lasis ŝin foriri”. Mi konsentas, ke _ig_ povus soni iom deviga, sed laŭ mia sperto estas normala uzo por indiki peton aŭ taskigon. Ĉu vi ankaŭ sentas trudon kaj devigon pri la vorto “sciigi”? Miasperte “sciigi” estas proksima al “informi”, ne al “altrudi scion”.

Comment: @Joffysloffy "_mi ne uzus_", meritas _downvote_? Mi ne opiniis _ig_ malĝusta, mi simple ĝin ne uzus en tiu situacio. Pri _ig_ kaj **ebla** elvoko pri devigo aŭ trudo sufiĉas [legi la unuan alineon de la difino de -ig/](http://vortaro.net/#igi). Kaj, oni ne povas aldoni _ig_ al io ajn. Ekzemple,  _taskigo_ en via frazo ne estas tre komprenebla. Kial? Ĉar la radiko estas substantiva, do la rezulto ne estas _taski_ + _igi_, sed _tasko_ + _igi_ (vidu I- C. en la difino). En la supre citita difino de _ig_ estas aliaj ekzemploj kie ĝi simple ne estas konvena, vidu RIM. 3, ekzemple.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Mi tiel voĉdonis, ĉar “mi ne uzus” en respondoj ĉi tie efektive signifas “ne uzu”, kaj mi malkonsentas pri la malrekomendo pri la uzo de _-ig-_ en la pridiskutata kazo. Mi celis diri ĝuste _igi ion tasko_ per la vorto _taskigo_, do laŭ mi tio estas bone komprenebla: “Mi lavigis miajn vestaĵojn” -> mi taskigis la lavadon de miaj vestaĵoj -> mi kreis por iu taskon kaj tiu tasko estas lavado me miaj vestaĵoj.

Comment: @Joffysloffy vi vere interpretemas. Mi ja povas skribi "ne uzu" se mi volas "mi ne uzus" signifas nur tion, ke _mi_ ne uzus. La originala mesaĝo uzas malĝuste _ig_, sed _lesivigi_ evidente ne ĝenas vin (!). Se "_Mi lesivis miajn lesivaĵojn_" ĝustas laŭ vi ... vi bone voĉdonis.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Ne nur mi interpretus tion tiel, sed la ĝenerala uzantaro de ĉi tiu retejo. Vi devas kompreni la jenan. De la perspektivo de la demandinto: ‘Vi ŝajne kapablas respondi la demandon, do verŝajne bone scias tion, kio estas ĝusta kaj ne. Do se _vi ne uzus_ ion, ankaŭ mi, la demandinto, _ne uzu tion_.’ Pro tio _mi ne uzus_ efektive signifas _ne uzu_, malgraŭ tio, kion vi ekzakte diras laŭvorte. Laŭ mi _lesivigi_ en la senco de _igi lesivi_ estas ebla uzo, sed ne estas klara. Eĉ _lesivi_ estas sufiĉe malofta por fari _lesivigi_ malfacile komprenebla; _lesivaĵo_ estu _lesivendaĵo_

Comment: En la sveda kaj la germana oni uzas verbojn _låta_ resp. _lassen_ en tiaj esprimoj. _Jag lät mitt byk tvättas/Ich ließ meine Wäsche gewaschen werden_, do kvankam _-igi_ estas pli bona, mi demandas min, ĉu _lasi_ kun volativo taŭgas. _Mi lasis, ke oni lavu miajn lavotaĵojn._ (Notu "**oni**", ne "ili", sed oni ne rajtas uzi "ili" en la espa en pasiva senco.) Aŭ ĉu _lasi + verbo_ ĉiam enhavas sencon de permeso?

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas Ankaŭ en la nederlanda ni uzas tiun verbon (_laten_) por tio, sed en Esperanto tio ne esprimas volon. Kun volitivo povas pli esprimi volon aŭ celon, sed ne kiel _igi_. Mi ne komprenas vian komenton pri ‘ili en pasiva senco’. Plue, jen citaĵo el [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#lasi): “La diferenco inter igi k[aj] lasi estas, ke igi signas volon, ordonon, efikan agon, dum lasi signas cedon, rezignacion, nekontraŭstaron”.

Comment: @Joffysloffy, per "ili en pasiva senco" mi celis la frazon "Mi lasis ilin lavi miajn vestaĵojn" de Eduardo. Oni ne povas diri tiel sen difini, pri kiuj "ili" temas.

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas Aha, jes, prave; se vi ne dirus, pri kiuj vi parolas, tio ne havus sencon.